Aligning/syncing one audio file to another using Python
I have 2 audio files recorded using laptop mic and one with external mic. Laptop mic recording starts after external mic. The time difference could be 2-60 seconds.
So I wrote this code which is pretty accurate, but when I bring both audio tracks (one from the video that uses laptop mic) and the newly adjusted audio, there is still like 50ms delay. Why could this be?

Sometimes it seems there is positive delay, and sometimes negative.

from scipy.signal import correlate
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
from scipy import signal
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import mediainfo

import numpy as np

def findOffset(audio1, audio2):
    correlation = signal.correlate(audio2, audio1, mode="full")
    lags = signal.correlation_lags(audio2.size, audio1.size, mode="full")
    lag = lags[np.argmax(correlation)]
    
    return lag


def adjustAudio(audio_segment, lag, frame_rate):
    # Convert lag from samples to milliseconds, rounding to nearest integer at the last step
    ms_lag = round((lag / frame_rate) * 1000)
    
    if lag > 0:
        # Audio needs to start later: pad audio at the beginning
        silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=ms_lag, frame_rate=frame_rate)
        adjusted_audio = silence + audio_segment
    else:
        # Audio needs to start earlier: trim audio from the beginning
        adjusted_audio = audio_segment[abs(ms_lag):]  # Use abs to convert negative lag to positive

    return adjusted_audio


def alignAudioTrack(audioFile, newAudioFile, lag):
    audio_data, rate, audio_segment = loadAudio(audioFile, return_segment=True)

    # Adjust the AudioSegment based on lag, ensuring frame_rate is passed correctly
    adjusted_audio = adjustAudio(audio_segment, lag, rate)

    # Fetch original bitrate
    bitrate = mediainfo(audioFile)['bit_rate']

    # Save the adjusted audio preserving the original bitrate
    adjusted_audio.export(newAudioFile, format="mp3", bitrate=bitrate)


def loadAudio(file_path, return_segment=False):
    audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_file(file_path)
    data = np.array(audio_segment.get_array_of_samples())
    if audio_segment.channels > 1:
        data = data.reshape((-1, audio_segment.channels)).mean(axis=1)  # Convert to mono if stereo
    rate = audio_segment.frame_rate

    if return_segment:
        return data, rate, audio_segment
    else:
        return data, rate

audio1, rate1 = loadAudio(audioFile1)
audio2, rate2 = loadAudio(audioFile2)
lag = findOffset(audio1, audio2)
alignAudioTrack(origAudioFile, alignedAudioFile,  lag)


If they're recorded using different asynchronous hardware, they could have clock drift that changes the alignment over the recording (or just sample rate offset that causes one to be slightly shorter than the other, etc.)

actually i found the issue it was about the audio extracted from the video had a delay. i am using moviepy VideoFileClip. So need to find a way to get the same audio without delay.

The mp3 de-/encoding messes up the alignment. Try exporting the audio to wav-format:
adjusted_audio.export(newAudioFile, format="wav", bitrate=bitrate)

Like this, the alignment should be perfect.

Thanks let me give this a try now.

Does it matter that I am comparing mp3 files though or do I need to convert those into wav also?

That does not matter. Once you have loaded them, they are no longer encoded. Just write the aligned ones as wav files. You probably have to adjust the bitrate or possibly other parameters.

Ok I just tried it and got the wav. I compare it with the mp3 but they look exactly the same so no change. I am using the same bitrate from the original so not sure what else I can do. I will check if other files have the same delay or not.

Ok I just checked it. Sometimes there is positive delay, sometimes negative. The editor I am using I can only zoom this much. But when I play both tracks, I hear double voice in any case.

Is the bitrate the mp3 bitrate? Like 128kbps or something? That is not applicable to the wav format. Wav is defined by sample rate and bit depth, e.g. 44100Hz and 16bit.

Could you add the code from "loadAudio" or a link to its documentation?

Yes it's 320kbps but when I print the rate from the loadAudio function I get 44100Hz. I will add it to OP.

This line: adjusted_audio = audio_segment[abs(ms_lag):]  is wrong, isn't it? It should be lag in samples, not ms.

I am not sure but I just checked here they also use ms? https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown # split sound1 in 5-second slices
slices = sound1[::5000]

You are right, pydub speciality. I would go for a cleaner solution and use pydub just to get numpy arrays from the mp3 files, align on a sample basis and then use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html to write the wav files.

Thx I will try this today.

Also in my case the first started audio will have some stuff not present in the shorter audio because it didn't start yet. Is that ok? But apart from the start there is 1:1 correspondence. Length wise they range from 1 min to an hour, but average len is probably 5-10 mins. I am using 3 min length for correlation.

3 min  are plenty. Correlation should yield a very prominent peak.

I just tried with numpy but correlate takes very long time it didnt finish. So basically the same findOffset function.

You can keep using scipy correlate. Just make sure you handle numpy arrays only and do all shifting and aligning in samples rather than ms.

Ok I see the issue now. It wasn't the algorithm which works perfectly but moviepy was extracting the audio track from mp4 with some delay. i have to why this happens.
